# rxHistorgram() Removing Factored Data

Tags: r, sql-server-2016, microsoft-r

I have been attempting to run the `RevoScaleR_SqlServer_GettingStarted.R` script that is part of the MS SQL Server 2016 package for a project I am working on. For some context, here is a PDF of the code that is provided by MS:

[packages.revolutionanalytics.com/doc/8.0.0/win/RevoScaleR_SqlServer_Getting_Started.pdf](http://packages.revolutionanalytics.com/doc/8.0.0/win/RevoScaleR_SqlServer_Getting_Started.pdf)

The code works well except for a strange error I receive when I attempt to run the `rxHistogram()` function as part of the tutorial. At step 3.2 of the tutorial it has me refine the data source by creating factors and identifying the min and max of specific variables. I run the `rxGetVarInfo()` function and receive the proper output as shown below:

[image]

The next step asks me to run the `rxHistogram()` function on the data and it seems to work well because it created the histogram in the pdf.

However, there is a consistent issue after I run this function that affects the running of the rest of the code, especially the `rxCube()` function which immediately follows. It seems that the rxHistogram() function removes the factors from my data. After some frustration, I re-ran the `rxGetDataInfo()` function and found my data had been changed.

[image]

NO FACTORS!!!

I would love to know if anyone else has seen or dealt with this issue and how it was solved? I have found the same issue with other `rx()` functions such as `rxCube()` so I feel there may be an issue in my environment setup.

Comment: improved formatting, added hyperlink and pictures